# How to ensure that a java class is loaded at application startup itself?

Tags: java, jvm, jscience

I have a class extending Jscience's SystemOfUnits to define some custom units. I want this class to be loaded by JVM even before any call to method Unit.valueOf() is invoked.

if the class is not loaded in JVM then below invocation fails as **java.text.ParseException: dz not recognized (in dz at index 0)**

```
 Unit.valueOf("dz");
```

-

```
 public final class CustomUnits extends SystemOfUnits {

 ...

 private static HashSet<Unit<?>> UNITS = new HashSet<Unit<?>>();

 public static final Unit<Dimensionless> DOZEN = customUnits(Unit.ONE
        .times(12));

 public static final Unit<Dimensionless> PIECE = customUnits(DOZEN
        .divide(12));

 static {
    UnitFormat.getInstance().label(CustomUnits.DOZEN, "dz");
    UnitFormat.getInstance().label(CustomUnits.PIECE, "pcs");
 }

 @Override
 public Set<Unit<?>> getUnits() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(UNITS);
 }

 ....
 }
```

Also be informed that this class will be part of a common jar which will be available as dependency to other main applications and i don't want every user to be informed that this class should be referred somewhere before Unit.valueOf() is called.

Looking for possible options that would enable a class to be loaded when the jar containing the custom class is loaded as dependency.

Wondering would spring bean initializing would be helpful.

Comment: You merely need to reference the class somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there is no options to tell JVM when to load a class. Class will be loaded only when some other class refers it.

Moreover, AFAIU you need `CustomUnits` not just to be *loaded* but to be *initialized* (to run static constructor). Initialization can be triggered by using static members of class as well as instance creation.

As a workaround, you can call `Class.forName(...)` method - it also guarantees class to be fully loaded and initialized.

Comment: I agree that Class.forName(..) could be used. But i don't what this to be informed to every users of the project. I decided to expose a static method CustomUnits.valueOf() which would in turn use Unit.valueOf(). Ensuring that the Custom class is loaded and initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try specifying the jar (with SystemOfUnits class) as dependency to your common jar containing the custom class? 
You can add these dependency in jar's Manifest file.